# MutationObserver in MutationObserver Callback

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I was adding a MutationObserver in my JavaScript code and applied it to a specific element in an iFrame. The detection works fine but now I need a second observer. After the first click in the iFrame the whole DOM of it changes and that's the moment where the first observer comes in and detects any other clicks on the navigation elements in the iFrame. Additionally to that I need to observe one div element and if it's text will be changed or not. So the idea was to create a second observer after a navigation button is clicked but it seems not to work since the second observer doesn't give any output on my console.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
        let observer = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => {
            let completed = false;
            var progress = $('iframe').contents().find('.overview-sidebar__header .progress-bar__percentage-bottom').first();
            let clickedClass = mutationRecords[0].target.attributes[0].nodeValue;
            
            if(clickedClass == 'transition-group') {
                console.log(progress.text());
                
                console.log(Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000));
            } else if(clickedClass == 'page-wrap' && !mutationRecords[0].nextSibling) {
                let secondObserver = new MutationObserver(mutationRecords => { console.log('Test') });

                secondObserver .observe($('iframe').contents().find('.transition-group').first()[0], {
                    childList: true,
                    subtree: true
                });

                console.log(Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000));
                
                $('iframe').contents().find('.section-lists .lesson-lists__item').each(function(index) {
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log($(this).find('.lesson-link__name > span').first().text());
                    
                    console.log($(this).find('.lesson-link__progress title').text().split('%')[0]);
                });
            }
        });
        
        observer.observe($('iframe').contents().find('.transition-group').first()[0], {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
```

The secondObserver in the else if branch is the problem here. Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: If the iframe navigates to a different URL, its old environment is entirely destroyed, listeners too.

Comment: No the content within the frame changes, the URL stays the same.

Comment: Try adding `characterData: true` to the observer's config parameter.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks!

Comment: It‘s running now. But when including an if statement in the second observer asking about the final level (there are 6 level, only want to enter if when reaching level 6) my observer fires 6 times at the same time. Somehow adding previous levels up. Is there a simple reason behind this why this could happen?

Comment: It means your code that adds the observer runs 6 times. There must have been 6 mutations.

Comment: Found my issue. Had to declare the observer function outside of the first observer, not inside else it would fire multiple times since there will be an additional observer with every click. Thanks for the help!